# retrieve a result from a python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am quite new to python. Any help would be appreciated.

Input of `verifyFace` are images `format.jpg` so what i want is to retrieve the `euclidean_distance` result from the function `verifyFace`

```
epsilon = 6.384185791015625e-08
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

this is what i want (example):

```
x = from verifyFace get euclidean_distance
```

second question after retreived the two element how can i select only the the the second element recover

```
 i=1
    if verifyFace(str(i)+"tst.jpg", "1train.jpg")=='0':
        a=0
    if verifyFace(str(i)+"tst.jpg", "1tst.jpg")=='1':
        b=1
```

Comment: you are not returing anything from the function verifyFace

Comment: Where is `epsilon` defined?

Comment: i'm returning 1 and 0 i need them for other operation ,epsilon is just a value

Comment: It is most certain a mis-indentation, I've posted an answer below.

Comment: i'm sorry typo error i edited my code

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if (cosine_similarity < epsilon):` block goes inside the function definition, not outside. Also, you need to pass `epsilon` inside the function

```
def verifyFace(img1, img2, epsilon):
    img1_representation = vgg_face_descriptor.predict(preprocess_image(img1))[0, :]
    img2_representation = vgg_face_descriptor.predict(preprocess_image(img2))[0, :]

    cosine_similarity = findCosineSimilarity(img1_representation, img2_representation)
    euclidean_distance = findEuclideanDistance(img1_representation, img2_representation)

    if (cosine_similarity < epsilon):
        print("verified... they are same person")
        return '1', euclidean_distance 
    else:
        print("unverified! they are not same person!")
        return '0', euclidean_distance
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to return multiple values from the function:

```
return '1', euclidean_distance
```

and when receiving:

```
ret_val, euclidean_distance = verifyFace(your_img1, your_img2, your_epsilon)
```

Comment: the if(cosine_similariy <epsilon) : block is inside the function , and i want to retreive the euclidean_distance from outside the function

Comment: you could return it like: `return '1', euclidean_distance` and receive it like `ret_val, euclidean_distance = verifyFace(img1, img2, epsilon)`